# MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

Getting this error while running migration in laravel. I Have rechecked my data type in the schema is a string.

As you can see in the schema the datatype is a string but still getting this error. Any solutions???

```
MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Expected "name" option to have type "string" but found "int"

at D:\CRUD\CRUD\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Exception\InvalidArgumentException.php:60
   56▕
   57▕             $expectedType = $typeString;
   58▕         }
   59▕
➜  60▕         return new static(sprintf('Expected %s to have type "%s" but found "%s"', $name, $expectedType, get_debug_type($value)));
   61▕     }
   62▕ }
   63▕

1   D:\CRUD\CRUD\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Model\IndexInput.php:71
    MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException::invalidType(""name" option", "string")

2   D:\CRUD\CRUD\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\CreateIndexes.php:118
    MongoDB\Model\IndexInput::__construct([])
```

##### Migration where it stopped

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
        $table->index('name');
        $table->unique('token', 64);
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: It is really easy, you are defining an `index` called `name`, but you are never telling what the column type is... instead of `$table->index('name');` try `$table->string('name')->index();`.

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried that. $table->string('name')->index(); and $table->string('name'); Still no luck could this is be an issue because of Laravel mongoDB package?

Comment: and what is the response ? Is it still the same error ?

Comment: Yes, Still the same. All other migrations have the same syntax but they are good. Migrations stops at this point

Comment: Are you sure then that this is the migration with problems ? I am thinking now that `64` could be the problem as it is referring to `int` and expects a `string`. Are you using Laravel Passport or Laravel Sanctum ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have changed the actual implementation of [`Laravel Sanctum migration`](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/b21e65cbe13896946986cb0868180cd69e1bd5d3/database/migrations/2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table.php#L9-L25).

[`$table->unique()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/31151477aa65e4ff2c76fc8ad33c423b7adf0bfa/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L507-L518) expects first parameter to be the column's `name` and second (optional) to be the unique index's `name`, but the original implementation uses [`$table->string('name', 64)->unique();`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/31151477aa65e4ff2c76fc8ad33c423b7adf0bfa/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L673-L678), so the first one is the column `name`, but the second one is the column's `size`, so that is not the same as a name...

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->unique('token');
```

I was delete lenght. It's work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32718968)